# Swinging factorial and swinging constant

Tags: factorial, applications, constants

The Swinging factorial $n≀$ defined as $$n≀=\frac{n!}{\left\lfloor{n/2}\right\rfloor!^2}$$ is relatively common and I found some results on Google. But when $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n≀}$$is calculated(by converting it into gamma and applying beta function) we get $\frac{8\pi\sqrt3}{27} + \frac{4}{3}$ which is quite a peculiar result and defining a constant(*swinging constant*)-$$e≀=\frac{8\pi\sqrt3}{27} + \frac{4}{3}$$ I wanted to ask that if there are any significant applications for both the swinging factorial and constant

Comment: Look at my answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689757/proving-pi-27s-36-8-sqrt3-where-s-sum-n-0-infty-frac-left-left/3689772#3689772

Comment: @Jan Thanks, but I want the applications, i had evaluated it by using a similar approach as yours

Comment: `$\wr$` gives $\wr$

Comment: http://oeis.org/A056040 lists some applications

Comment: @saulspatz thanks!

Comment: This is interesting. As someone who doesn't know anything about this, two questions: it is possible to analytically extend $\wr$ to the whole line just as $\Gamma$ extends $!$? If so, does ${\rm e}\wr$ actually coincide with swinging constant, i.e., is ${\rm e}\wr$ more than just a notation?

Comment: @Ivo Terek the first question is a nice question, by looking at the uses/application/equivalent definitions we see that $n\wr$ is mostly used as a series coefficient or used in number theory as it yields only natural numbers. For the second question, I don't think just substituting value of e will do the work, the analytical extension will help us do that.